# Prove that if f is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ then $f(z)=\lambda z+c$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the form $f(x+iy)=u(x)+iv(y)$ where $u,v$ are real functions. Prove that $$f(z)=\lambda z+c$$ 
 for  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

---

How do I prove this? I think I have to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations somehow but I can't quite figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand.  $v$ is a function of $x$?  So $f$ is only defined on the points $x+iv(x)$?  Is $x$ meant to be real?

Comment: Sorry, I made two mistakes, those are fixed now and the question should now make sense